# Интерьер помещения — плеоназм или нет?

Tags: грамотная-речь, плеоназм

Попалось в тексте словосочетание "интерьер помещения". Но, по идее, если интерьер, то в любом случае чего-то, что находится внутри. То есть является ли это выражение плеоназмом?

Answer (score 6):

У любого помещения, может быть как внутреннее убранство (интерьер), так и внешнее (как минимум, входная дверь или её отсутствие). Соответственно, *интерьер помещения*, плеоназмом являться не будет.

Comment: Согласна с ответом. Плеоназма не будет, т.к. интерьер в переводе "внутренний","между". Плеоназмом будет, например, "интерьер внутри здания".

Answer (score -2):

Это не плеоназм. Наиболее вероятно, что это солецизм.

Comment: Солецизм - синтаксически неправильный оборот речи. А этот оборот синтаксически правильный.